# why does the cursor go to the second line after the first input

Tags: arrays, c

I'm trying to solve exercise 1-19 in the 2nd edition of "The C programming language"

The exercise says: Write a function reverse(s) that reverses the character string s. Use it to write a program that reverses its input a line at a time.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* exercise 1-19 */

#define MAXLENGTH 1000

void reverse(char input[], int arraylength);

main (){
    int userinput, i;
    char inputarray[MAXLENGTH];

    i = 0;
    while ((userinput = getchar()) != EOF){
        if ( userinput == '\n' || i == (MAXLENGTH-1)){
            inputarray[i] = '\0';
            reverse(inputarray, i);
            i = 0;
        }
        inputarray[i] = userinput;
        ++i;
    }
}

void reverse(char input[], int arraylength){
    int i;
    for (i = (arraylength-1); i >= 0; --i){
        printf("%c", input[i]);
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

The code works but if you run it and enter the first input, the cursor doesn't go to a newline after the output. This only happens for the first output.

What is causing this? and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please *show* the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: You're attempting to rewrite the `fgets` function. The description for the assignment doesn't preclude using `fgets`.

Comment: @kaylum I added pictures

Comment: Please be aware of the fact that the K&R book, while very good, is outdated and some constructs that it teaches are no longer a part of the C language.  For example, `main()` is no longer valid C since the "implicit int" rule has been removed.

Comment: As for your question, figure out at which point `\n` becomes a part of the `inputarray`. I recommend using a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Consider what your `reverse` function is doing. You never actually print a newline character.

You may find it more useful to write your `reverse` function to return a reversed `char *` that you can then print.

Comment: The book doesn't talk about pointers at this point in the book. So I want to keep it strict to the knowledge I have at this point.

Comment: Fair enough. Once you figure this out, maybe that's something you can challenge yourself with.

Answer (score 0):

This line after the `if` statement,

```
inputarray[i] = userinput;
```

saves the newline character after you reset the index to 0. Meaning that it saves it in the **first position** in the array.

When you input `\n` for the **first time**, your first array element isn't '\n' but the first letter you type, therefore no newline is printed.

Also, `main()` should be of type `int` by standard. The following should do what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* exercise 1-19 */

#define MAXLENGTH 1000

void reverse(char input[], int arraylength);

int main (){
    int userinput, i;
    char inputarray[MAXLENGTH];

    i = 0;
    inputarray[i] = '\n'; /* place the newline character at the first position */
    ++i; /* increment i */

    while ((userinput = getchar()) != EOF){
        if ( userinput == '\n' || i == (MAXLENGTH-1)){
            inputarray[i] = '\0';
            reverse(inputarray, i);
            i = 0;
        }
        inputarray[i] = userinput;
        ++i;
    }
     return 0;
}

void reverse(char input[], int arraylength){
    int i;
    for (i = (arraylength-1); i >= 0; --i){
        printf("%c", input[i]);
    }
}
```